# Unable to build ionic error : Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: "C:\Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_291

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework

I am trying to execute this command

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

and I get the following error :

```
    Build at: 2021-07-06T09:28:20.394Z - Hash: 933d6e73ee2cc923ca07 - Time: 62511ms
> cordova.cmd build android --release
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\daees\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\daees\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK version 8 installed.
You can get it from the following location:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: "C:\Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_291
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --release exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I tried different solution already discussed but none of them worked for me

Although this says my JAVA_HOME is invalid, but I don't think so, I have it installed and I've added it as environment and System variable

What do I do?
Please help

[image]

Comment: Share Screenshot of your system variables.

Comment: `Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: "C:\Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_291` It seems you have a double quote in the middle of the path

Comment: Is Java installed in "C:\Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_291? Try to  execute Java directly

Comment: @MatPag yes, i saw that in one of the solutions on stackoverflow, but didn't work for me.. and On removing quotes, there is no difference in the output either

Comment: @8bit I typed java --version in cmd, I got no output but no error either, is there something wrong with installation ?

Comment: @SadafShafi can you try using like this in environment variables C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_291 ?? I hope this might do a trick

Comment: @karthikakinapelli just tried that too,  got the same error for that too :((

Comment: @SadafShafi can you try to install to a different location like C:\Installers\Java\jdk1.8.0_291 and try setting path in environment variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply uninstalled all the versions of JDK and then installed V1.8 again and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `"` from the JAVA_PATH so it looks like this: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291`

Comment: Just did, having it or not having it made no changes